# Would "Human Resources are excited or is excited" correct?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

Would "Human Resources are excited or is excited" be correct?

Comment: Probably depends on American vs. British English. In British English, "Human Resources are" is likely fine since there are presumably many people working in the department. In American English, "Human Resources is" would likely be the only choice for native speakers.

Comment: Make that “Many British Anglophones treat collective nouns (corporations, departments, etc.) as plural (ie needing plural concord) when the individual members of the collection are being referenced metonymically/synecdochally..." and I'll agree wholeheartedly.

Comment: Both are incorrect, because HR never gets excited.

Answer (score 1):

In the example given, *Human Resources* is shorthand for *the Human Resources Department*. It is logically singular. As such, the verb should be *is*.

There are some cases when a plural might be called for

> In many modern companies, human resources are their most valuable assets.

Note that, in this latter example, there is no capitalization, since the phrase is not the name of anything, but a generic descriptor.

**SUPPLEMENT**: The above explanation reflects US usage. Other English speaking countries may differ.

Comment: I don't see how you can claim _Human Resources_ is short for _Human Resources Department_ rather than _The staff of the Human Resources Department_. Either is possible; more common in Australia would be 'Australia' [short for 'the Australian team'] 'is winning 3 - 0.' More common in the UK would be 'Australia' [short for 'the members of the Australian team'] 'are winning 3 - 0.' The **latter** usage is what is termed 'logical accord' or 'notional accord' (or 'synesis').

Comment: @EdwinAshworth As noted in a few comments, this may be regional. In US, singular would be more likely. If the term *staff* were inserted, either would work.

Comment: So why the parochial answer?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth My answer is parochial because my knowledge is similarly constrained. Edited to acknowledge that.

Comment: Apparently, staff at [Campbell University, NC](http://www.campbell.edu/faculty-staff/human-resources/) also prefer logical agreement to superficial agreement: '... Human Resources have been working with co-workers in developing health care programs for employees....' The terms 'British English' and 'American English' are misleading.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth My view is far from a rule.